# How can I replace all '&amp%3B' with '&' in my _GET url via htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link like `https://my.com/list.php?login=test&amp%3Bpassword=test&amp%3Btype=m3u` and trying to replace all `&amp%3B` with `&` via .htaccess My rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&amp%3B(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&%2 [L,R=301]
```

Don't work. 
How can I change all amp%3B in url to & using the .htaccess file?

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML lines where we can see the link?

Comment: give me some context, please. Why do you have a link in such a form? I only ask because it would be better to change it programatically on an earlier stage

Comment: Programmatically the reference can't be changed since the request is made by other website. It is necessary to change through .htaccess With my rule the reference changes on: /list.php?login=test&amp%253Bpassword=test&type=m3u

Comment: I am not sure if the %{QUERY_STRING} variable still contains `%3B` - that might have been URL-decoded at this point already. So try matching for `;` in that place instead.

Comment: Or, if you can’t get this to work using rewriting, an alternative might be to simply handle this in your PHP script. If my test is working correctly, instead of `password` and `test`, this seems to cause two entries in $_GET with the keys `amp;password` and `amp;test` - so you could easily check whether those are set, and if so “create” the corresponding $_GET entries with the correct keys from that (and then maybe unset the false keys after, if those could cause trouble later on in the application/script.)

Comment: The problem is solved, rule: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)&amp%3B(.*)
RewriteRule .* /list.php?%1&%2 [N,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about REQUEST_URI.

Also since you are working with QUERY_STRING 
 you don't need brackets in RewriteRule

Besides be sure you have *"RewriteEngine On"* above

Here is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(&amp;|&amp%3B)(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%3 [L,R=301]
```

It works with & and &amp%3B. See second "()".